# Check Dictionary to containing nil values and empty values

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to check my dictionary to containing nil or empty value (nil and ""), add show it on the UI 
my dictionary contains string and int values

```
let params = [
        "token":APItoken.getToken(),
        "gender":gender_id,
        "car_number":number_car,
        "car_model":car_model,
        "year_of_birth":1998,
        "car_year":create_year,
        "seats_number":sits,
        "facilities":fac,
        "type":typeID
        ] as [String : Any]
```

I try to use this code, but it doesn't work

```
  if params.values.filter({ $0 == nil }).isEmpty
    {
        print("full")
    }
    else
    {
        print("empty")
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check If Swift Dictionary Contains No Values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414788/check-if-swift-dictionary-contains-no-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of `Dictionary` from *[String:Any] to [String:Any?]* to compare **values to nil**

```
let someDict = ["first":"name","second":1,"third":1.2,"someNilValue":nil] as [String:Any?]

func checkEmptyDict(_ dict:[String:Any?]) -> Bool {

for (_,value) in dict {
    if value == nil || value as? String == "" { return true }
   }

return false

}

checkEmptyDict(someDict) //returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change params type [String : Any] to [String : Any?] 
your Code for check nil is correct just need to add empty string condition
like :

```
       if params.values.filter({
            if let x = $0 {
                if let str = x as? String , str.isEmpty {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }).isEmpty
        {
            print("not contain nil value ")
        }
        else
        {
            print("contain nil value ")
        }
```