# How to check the null condition for JSON response?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to check the null condition for one of the dictionaries of json response.But when i checking the condition, I am getting an error like **"Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String : Any]' and 'JSON'"**.I am getting this error at the line of `if !(chattt == JSON.null)`.If any one helps me to solve this,would be great.Thanks in advance.

```
 let acce:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access-tokenn")!
        print(acce)

        let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(acce)","Content-Type":"application/X-Access-Token"]
        print((Constants.Chatlistsearch)+(idd))
        Alamofire.request((Constants.Chatlistsearch+idd), method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {  response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                //print(response)
                if response.result.value != nil{
                    var maindictionary = NSDictionary()
                    maindictionary = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                  //  print(maindictionary)

                    var chat:Dictionary = maindictionary.value(forKey: "data") as! [String:Any]
                   // print(chat)

                    var chatt:Dictionary = chat["user"] as! [String:Any]
                   // print(chatt)

                    var chattt:Dictionary = chat["chat"] as! [String:Any]
                    print(chattt)



                    if !(chattt == JSON.null) {
                        let viewc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as? ChatViewController
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewc!, animated: true)
                    }else{
                        print("Find Action")
                    }


//                    self.data = [String(stringInterpolationSegment: chatt["unique_id"])]
//                    print(self.data)

                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: chattt variable is dictionary type, so when you  need check if is null just do that `if chattt != nil`

Comment: check this for e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414788/check-if-swift-dictionary-contains-no-values

Comment: try this : `if !chattt.isEmpty`

Comment: Those force unwraps can crash your code so easily that would make your nil check irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
if let chattt = chat["chat"] as? [String:Any] {
    //It's available. Execute further tasks
} else {
    //It's nil or chat["chat"] type is not dictionary.
}
```

You can either do it using guard.

```
guard let chattt = chat["chat"] as? [String:Any] else {
    //Using this, the further code will never execute as implemented force return here
    return
}
```

if any issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

do the following

```
guard let chattt = chat["chat"] as? [String:Any] else {
    let viewc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as? ChatViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewc!, animated: true)
    return
}
```